# Finding ALL local and global minima and maxima of function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Given a function with 2 variables, how does one find the ALL the local and global minimas and maximas. For example, how does one find them for
$$f(x,y)=(x^2+12y-1)^2
+(49x^2+49y^2+84x+2324y-681)^2$$

Comment: where is the function?

Comment: @parcly has made an edit, thanks :)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: Have you learned partial derivatives yet? And how to use partial derivatives to find critical (or stationary) points of a function? And then the second derivatives method (using the Hessian matrix) to examine them?

Comment: @zipirovich i have learned it to do it for function with one variable. Not sure how to do it for 2 or more variable.

Comment: Okay, let's try one question at a time. Do you know the concept of ***partial derivatives***?

Comment: @zipirovich thanks for your patience. these are the concepts that I know, taking derivative, partial derivative, finding hessian matrix. Also how to find local minima, maxima or saddle points for functions with one variables (differentiating the function w.r.t to x and equating it to zero and solve for x)